# ReSwift ActionCreator with callback / returning observable after dispatch

Tags: swift, rx-swift, swift4, reswift

I'm using [ReSwift](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift) and [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) (without that information the question wouldn't make much sense).

Is there a standard way of dispatching an action creator in ReSwift and having something happened after it's finished processing (i.e., finished processing actions and all internal requests that might happen inside the action creator)?

I do know one way to achieve this:

```
func myActionCreator(_ callback: () -> Void) -> (state: AppState, store: Store<AppState>) -> Action? {
    return { state, store in
        _ = someRequest().subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            callback()
        })

        return nil
    }
}

store.dispatch(myActionCreator({
    // callback
}))
```

But there are 2 issues with this:

1. I'd rather use a standard way
2. I also need this callback as an `Observable` object.

To explain the second reason, I need something like:

`let observable = store.dispatch(myActionCreator)`

so I can use the `observable` variable as I please.

Sure, I could implement all that loging myself and have something like a `store.dispatchReturningObservable` as an extension of the `Store`, but I'm looking for a simpler way.

Is there one?

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I've come up with was this:

```
extension Store {

    func dispatchObservable(_ callbackActionCreator: @escaping (@escaping () -> Void) -> (State, Store<State>) -> Action?) -> Observable<State> {
        return Observable.create({ observer in
            let actionCreator = callbackActionCreator({
                observer.onNext(self.state)
                observer.onCompleted()
            })

            self.dispatch(actionCreator)

            return Disposables.create()
        })
    }

}
```

I won't accept this answer, because I'm still looking for a simpler / more standard way.